# set root component in angular child module

Tags: angular, typescript, module, routes, lazy-loading

I have a working app routing and i want to add lazy loading.

This ist the working app-routing.module.ts file (without lazy loading):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './routes/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './routes/register/register.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './routes/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './routes/profile/profile.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  {
    path: 'app', component: NavigationComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now i created a child module for the "navigation" section (navigation.module.ts):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './routes/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './routes/profile/profile.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [NavigationComponent]
})
export class NavigationModule { }
```

And this is the new app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './routes/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './routes/register/register.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './routes/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './routes/profile/profile.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  {
    path: 'app', loadChildren: () => import('./navigation/navigation.module').then(m => m.NavigationModule)
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now I have two different behaviours when I call for example /app/profile:

Behaviour without lazy loading (desired):

```html
<app-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-navigation>
    <!-- sidebar and toolbar content -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-profile>
      <!-- profile content -->
    </app-profile>
  </app-navigation>
</app-root>
```

Behaviour with lazy loading:

```html
<app-root>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-profile>
    <!-- profile content -->
  </app-profile>
</app-root>
```

How is it possible to have the same behaviour with lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NavigationModule try

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavigationComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  ]
];
```